# How to create basic table in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to make a table of 10 columns. I want also to find the **row with the minimum value in column 0**.

Example:

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6,]
[7,8,9]
[10,11,21]]
```

How do I get to the row which have minimum value of column 0? **I just need a function that can use column 0.**
[1,2,3]

Comment: You tagged two popular options already: `numpy` and `pandas`. Why not use one of them?

Comment: actually i trying to them. but i did not found minimum value in column 0. (i do not know row number. Row len is always changing. )

Comment: [`np.argmin(a[:, 0])`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `numpy` `arange` we can easily create a range of numbers, and then reshape them into a 2d array:

```
In [70]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(4,3)                                     
In [71]: arr                                                                    
Out[71]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

`argmin` gives the index of the minimum value, for the whole array (flattened) or by row or column:

```
In [72]: np.argmin(arr, axis=1)                                                 
Out[72]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

The 0 column:

```
In [73]: arr[:,0]                                                               
Out[73]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])
In [74]: np.argmin(arr[:,0])                                                    
Out[74]: 0
```

`pandas` makes a nice table.

```
In [76]: import pandas as pd                                                    
In [77]: df = pd.DataFrame(arr)                                                 
In [78]: df                                                                     
Out[78]: 
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin function for that `range`.
Range does not create a list but an iterator wich behave quite like a list and should be way enough for you (iterator are "lists" but their item are calculated only when requested).

So :

```py
a = range(10)
print(a) #-> range(0, 10)
for i in a:
    print(a) #-> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 

print(a[2]) #-> 2
print(a[0]) #-> 0
```

If you want not to start from 0 just put `range(start_value, end_value)`.
And if you want a custom increment use `range(start_value, end_value, increment)` (the default increment is 1 but if you want to go backward you can use -1).

## Edit:

To create a table like your example you can use this small function :

```py
def ct(nStart, nEnd, nPerSubTable):
 r = [] # Setup initial variable
 subTable = []
 for i in range(nStart, nEnd): # The main ranging
  subTable.append(i)
  if len(subTable) == nPerSubTable: # When the len of the sub table hit the requested one append to r and reset sub table
   r.append(subTable)
   subTable = []
 if len(subTable) > 0: # If there is some left over because the last subtable is smaller than expected, add it any way
  r.append(subTable)
 return r
```

Comment: I need to use the array as a table and I have to reach the minimum value in column 0 with a row.

Comment: I don't really understand, would you an multi dimensional table ? (a list of lists ?)

Comment: Yes, multi dimensional table.

Comment: Okay but what do you want in the remaining columns ?

Comment: I gave my example and edited my question, you can look

Comment: The smallest value is in [0][0].

Comment: Can you please clarify how you would this creation process to be made ? (I don't think what I've done statisfy that)

Comment: Thank you for answer, Jorropo. I know that [0][0] is giving solution. But I mean, I don't know which row has the minimum. I just need a function that can use column 0.